# Для чего используется конструктор с параметром типа Parcel?

Tags: java, android

```
public class Party implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private Integer code;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    private String msg;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();

    protected Party(Parcel in) {    //зачем этот конструктор?
        msg = in.readString();
        data = in.readParcelable(Data.class.getClassLoader()); // правильно ли я тут написал??
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор `Party(Parcel in)` используется для создания объекта типа `Party` исходя из объекта `Parcel in`.

`Parcel` – это некий контейнер для данных.

Обычно подобные конструкторы используются в случаях реализации классом интерфейса `Parcelable`. В свою очередь, объект класса, реализующий интерфейс `Parcelable` может быть помещен в `Intent` для передачи его куда-либо.

Подробнее с `Parcel` можно ознакомиться [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).

Comment: data = in.readParcelable(Data.class.getClassLoader()); // правильно ли я тут написал??